# Exclude pages using an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

For the life of me I can't see why this isn't working.

I am trying to get this selection list to show all pages except for a couple that I want to exclude. I'm doing this by simply getting the page by title and then it's ID from that.

```
<select>
<?php
// Get these pages by their title
$page1 = get_page_by_title('My First Page');
$page2 = get_page_by_title('My Second Page');

// The pages to be excluded
$excludeThese = array(
$page1->ID . ',' . 
$page2->ID
);

// Args for WP_Query   
$args = array(
'post__not_in' => $excludeThese, 
'post_type' => 'page', 
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'order' => 'asc'
);

$pages_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($pages_query->have_posts()) : $pages_query->the_post();?>
<option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</select>
```

If I echo $page1 and $page2, the ID's of the pages are shown, so therefore the $excludeThese array should be using them (yes?).

If I hardcode the ID's into the $excludeThese array instead like this...

```
$excludeThese = array(1, 2);
```

...then it all works fine. So it appears the $excludeThese array isn't working properly.

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Cheers y'all.

Comment: `post__not_in` should be `post_not_in` (one underscore after `post`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// The pages to be excluded
$excludeThese = array(
    $page1->ID,
    $page2->ID
);
```

You should use that instead of this:

```
// The pages to be excluded
$excludeThese = array(
    $page1->ID . ',' . 
    $page2->ID
);
```

Comment: FFS - can't believe I didn't pick up on that. Well done and thanks - it works (obviously) as do the solutions offered by rationalboss and celeriko below.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to concatenate the arguments to `array()`

```
$excludeThese = array($page1->ID, $page2->ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// The pages to be excluded
$excludeThese = array(
$page1->ID . ',' .  // there is a concatenation of string here
$page2->ID
);
```

Because of the string concatenation, your `$excludeThese would be`array('1,2');`

It should be:

```
// The pages to be excluded
$excludeThese = array(
$page1->ID , 
$page2->ID
);
```